# Ajax getting into on error exactly after 2 mins

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

below is my ajax code, i am getting data from web method , normally it works good, but if i keep my application idle for 2 min, then on next ajax call it will go to error. how can i debug this , like how can i print the error information on screen, i tried below methods but not getting anything. I added a paragraph element testing and trying to show error in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyAjax(_URL, _DATA, _CallBack) {
            var mrnvalue = document.getElementById('MRN01').value;
            var deviceID = document.getElementById('DeviceID01').value;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: apppath + _URL,
                data: JSON.stringify({ MRN: mrnvalue, DeviceID: deviceID }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 5000,
                success: function (msg) {
                    _CallBack(msg.d);
                },
                //error: function (err) {  
                    //$("#testing").html("ERROR IN AJAX CALL");
                   // setTimeout(function () { callDefaultPage() }, 10000);
                //}

                error: OnError

            });
        }
        function OnError(xhr, errorType, exception) {
            var responseText;
            $("#testing").html("error: ");
            try {
                responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                $("#testing").append(errorType + "\n" + exception);
                $("#testing").append(responseText.ExceptionType + "\n");
                $("#testing").append(responseText.StackTrace + "\n");
                $("#testing").append(responseText.Message + "\n");
            } catch (e) {
                responseText = xhr.responseText;
                $("#testing").html(responseText);
            }
        }

    </script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="formCenter">
<p id="testing" runat="server"></p>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the console?  What happens when you step through in a debugger?

Comment: actually this is the issue, i deployed this application on IIS, when i run in IE or anyother browser using laptop all is good, but when i am running it on 10" display (samsung db10e-t) it get into ajax error area after 2 min idle time. i tested it by adding that `$("#testing").html("ERROR IN AJAX CALL");`. its very strange issue. so i want to display error details on page.